# SimpleInjector can't inject string after update

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

After updating SimpleInjector from version 2.8.3 to v3.0.1, it returns an error when I try to pass the connection string into a constructor. This was working fine in the past but after the update something is wrong. Error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in SimpleInjector.dll
>
> Additional information: The constructor of type MwmJobUpdateNotifier
>   contains parameter 'connectionString' of type String which can not be
>   used for constructor injection.

Here is where the SimpleInjector container is configured:

```
    public static Container Configure(Container container)
    {
        // Force assembly reference so Interfaces load correctly.
        if (typeof(IJobRepository) != null) 
            container.RegisterAllInterfacesForClassesInAssemblyContaining<JobRepository>();

        // Force assembly reference so Interfaces load correctly.
        if (typeof(IGmcService) != null)
            container.RegisterAllInterfacesForClassesInAssemblyContaining<GmcService>();

        container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
        container.Register<IMwmJobUpdateNotifier>(() => new MwmJobUpdateNotifier(container.GetInstance<IJobRepository>(),
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Coordinate_DatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString));
        container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false;

        MWM.Service.DAL.Config.AGI.AGIIocConfig.Configure(container);

        return container;
    }
```

It looks like doesn't like the way I pass the two parameters into the constructor.

Edited: The exception is triggered within my `ContainerException` class where all interfaces are registered:

```
public static Container RegisterAllInterfacesForClassesInAssemblyContaining<T>(this Container container, Lifestyle lifestyle = null) where T : class
    {
        var assembly = typeof(T).Assembly;

        var registrations = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass && 
                type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Except(type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetInterfaces()))
                    .Except(type.BaseType.GetInterfaces())
                    .Any())
            .Select(type => new 
            { 
                Services = type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Except(type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetInterfaces()))
                    .Except(type.BaseType.GetInterfaces()), 
                Implementation = type
            });

        foreach (var registration in registrations)
        {
            foreach (var service in registration.Services)
            {
                if (registration.Implementation.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                {
                    if (lifestyle == null)
                    {
                        container.Register(service.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), registration.Implementation.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        container.Register(service.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), registration.Implementation.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), lifestyle);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lifestyle == null)
                        container.Register(service, registration.Implementation);
                    else
                        container.Register(service, registration.Implementation, lifestyle);
                }
            }
        }

        return container;
    }
```

The exception is captured in the penultimate `container.Register(...)` call.

Comment: On which line do you get that exception?

Comment: This wasn't supported in v2 either. Could it be that for some reason the `MwmJobUpdateNotifier` is auto-wired, where it pteviously wasn't?

Comment: I get the exception in "conatiner.Register(service, registration.Implementation);". If I downgrade the nuget packages to v2.8.3 I don't get the exception anymore. I see in the breaking changes for v3, this SI version is more restrictive https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/releases

Comment: It's interesting that you can no longer replace the registration before the container spots the string constructor argument. I guess one solution is to pass a list of types to exclude to `RegisterAllInterfacesForClassesInAssemblyContaining`.

Comment: Please can you include the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but from what I'm reading here: [How do I pass a parameter to the constructor using Simple Injector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785822/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-the-constructor-using-simple-injector)

it seems you/we have to change the design so that run-time values are not dependencies of the constructor.

In my particular situation, the object is a database service and needs connection strings parameters, which are stored in a config file, making them run-time values because of the different environments in the release pipeline.

My repositories project can't access the config file directly (tho I suppose it could but it felt wrong to me to try) so I introduced an ad-hoc value dependency resolver.   This object is just a wrapper around a dictionary with some management methods to add, remove, update, merge and check for required values so each object that depends on it can check it provides the required items.

```
public interface IResolver 
{
    void Add<T>(string key, T keyValue);
    T Resolve<T>(string key);
    bool ResolvesAll(params string[] keys);
}

public sealed class Resolver : IResolver
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> directory;

    public void Add<T>(string key, T keyValue)
    {
        if (directory.ContainsKey(key))
          directory[key] = keyValue;
        else
          directory.Add(key, keyValue);
    }

    public T Resolve<T>(string key) 
    {
        return directory.ContainsKey(key) ? directory[key] as T : default(T);
    }
    public bool ResolvesAll(params string[] keys)
    {
        return keys.All(k => directory.ContainsKey(k));
    }

}
```

Then the container just registers the resolver:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IResolver, Resolver>(new Resolver());
```

And the dependent classes receive the auto-wired object.

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    private readonly IResolver resolver;
    public SomeClass(IResolver resolver)
    {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(string whatever)
    {
        if (!resolver.ResolvesAll("fred", "barny", "wilma"))
           throw new Exception("missing dependencies");

        var fred = resolver.Resolve<string>("fred");
        SomeOtherMethod(fred, whatever);
    }
}
```